# Text entry input source changes after every reboot

Tags: keyboard-layout

I am running Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS. I only ever want English (UK) keyboard text entry. In the Text Entry settings, I have only one entry present and selected: English (UK).

However, when I reboot my computer, it begins using some other text entry that I suspect is English (US). My `\` and `<` get switched, for example.

To fix this, I have to select English (UK) from the Text Entry settings (even though it's already selected and the only option there).

What's going on? How can I fix this permanently?